# Python class decorators with arguments, but decorated function is not being run

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've got this working for the most part. I want to have a class decorator (`Decorator` class) that accepts arguments (`greeting` and `farewell`) that can be used to wrap a method on an object (an instance of `Person`).

Everything is working fine, except... the original command function on the `Person` class is never run! If I manually call the function using something like

```
output = getattr(instance, func.func_name)(command, *args, **kwargs)
```

I get infinite recursion.

How do I do this? The full code is listed below:

```
import functools

class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, greeting, farewell, *args, **kwargs):
        print "initing"
        self.greeting = greeting
        self.farewell = farewell

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        print "CALLING"

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(instance, command, *args, **kwargs):
            return "%s, %s! %s!\n%s, %s!" % (
                self.greeting,
                instance.name,
                command,
                self.farewell,
                instance.name
            )
        return wrapper

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @Decorator("Hello", "Goodbye")
    def command(self, data):
        return data + "LIKE A BOSS"

s = Person("Bob")
print s.command("eat food")
```

Actual output:

```
initing
CALLING
Hello, Bob! eat food!
Goodbye, Bob!
```

Expected output:

```
initing
CALLING
Hello, Bob! eat food LIKE A BOSS!
Goodbye, Bob!
```

Comment: Based on your usage example, `__call__` only needs to take one argument: `func`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never called `func` to get the original message:

```
def wrapper(instance, command, *args, **kwargs):
            original_value = func(instance, command) #call func here
            return "%s, %s! %s!\n%s, %s!" % (
                self.greeting,
                instance.name,
                original_value,
                self.farewell,
                instance.name
            )
```

**Output:**

```
initing
CALLING
Hello, Bob! eat food LIKE A BOSS!
Goodbye, Bob!
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call func(data) somewhere in your wrapper to get the "LIKE A BOSS" result and add it to the expected output